# adding new sockets to epoll instances other than the epoll instance that polls the listening socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, file-descriptor, epoll

The situation:

- Multiple processes share the same file descriptor table.
- Each process listens to its own epoll instance.
- All sockets and calls involving them are non-blocking.
- Among those processes, only process A adds the listening socket to its epoll instance.
- Process A knows the fds of the epolls of all other processes.
- When a new socket (i.e. a new connection) arrives, process A adds it to an epoll instance of one of the other processes...

...like so:

```
int new_sfd;
while ((new_sfd = accept4(listening_fd, NULL, NULL, SOCK_NONBLOCK)) != -1) {
    if (epoll_ctl(other_epoll_fds[new_sfd % PROCESS_C], EPOLL_CTL_ADD, new_sfd,
                  &(struct epoll_event){
                      .data = {.fd = new_sfd},
                      .events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLET
                  }) == -1) {
        perror("Failed to add a new socket to an epoll instance");
        close(new_sfd);
    }
}
if (errno != EAGAIN) {
    perror("Failed to accept one or more incoming connections");
}
```

This seems to work (i.e. no errors occur at this stage). When a connection comes in at process A, it gets added to the epoll of a process B, after which process B gets an event with the EPOLLIN flag set, as expected. Process B then obtains the fd of the new socket by reading the data.fd member of the received epoll_event structure, and attempts a `recv()` on said fd.

Here things go unexpectedly wrong. `recv()` returns -1 with the following error: `Socket operation on non-socket`.

What gives? By inserting a lot of debugging `printf()` statements everywhere, I've thoroughly verified that the fd value returned by `accept4()` in process A is in fact the same as the fd value that I pass as the first argument to `recv()` in process B (and again, all processes share the same file descriptor table), so I can't make any sense of this. Help?! D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of Googling later, and I've landed on the following page:

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2356101/

Apparently `execve()` undos the sharing of the file descriptor table that I had set up with `clone()` and the `CLONE_FILES` flag (so any socket fd appearing after `execve()` is called causes a copy-on-write of the table for the listening process A, rendering the change invisible to the other processes).

I was just unlucky enough that this behavior of `execve()` is not yet documented in the current version of the manuals. Hence the above patch by Kevin Easton (thanks, Kevin). Also, thanks, [Devolus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2282011/devolus) for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Funnily, your question made me aware of a rather similar problem in my servercode, which I was unaware of and could now fix before it even leaded to problems later on. :)

Answer (score 1):

If A and B are really two separate processes, then they have a different set of filedescriptors. So Descriptor 6 in A is not neccessarily the same as 6 in B. If the return value indicates that the FD is not a socket, then it probably isn't, but this is not visible from your code. Verifiny with printf that you pass the same FD only made sure that these FD have the same values, but that doesn't mean that they are the same, as they are most likely not.

Comment: No, I mentioned twice in my question that the processes *do* share the same file descriptor table. How? Well, all the processes are spawned from the same parent process with `clone()` and the `CLONE_FILES` flag set. See the manual page for `clone()` for more information, if needed.

Comment: However..... after `clone()`ing, I do call `exec()` in the child processes. Now, AFAIK `exec()` does nothing with the file descriptor table other than closing any fds that have the `FD_CLOEXEC` flag set, but maybe I'm wrong..? Worth double checking, I guess. Thanks for bringing me on an idea, at least. :)

Comment: I noticed that you mentioned that they share the FDs, but you never mentioned how you achieved this, so this could be a potential wrong assumption as long as we don't see the code. ;)

Comment: Agreed. I probably should have mentioned how the fd table is shared in the question, but didn't want to make it longer than it already is...